# nginx error recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.152.129

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as the HTTP server and PHP FPM. Now my website can be accessed normally. However, the following error messages appear in the error log of nginx:

```
2020/04/23 12:34:27 [info] 8604#0: *106419377 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.152.129, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:27 [info] 8604#0: *106419378 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.151.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:27 [info] 8604#0: *106419379 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.151.129, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:27 [info] 8603#0: *106419380 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.152.131, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:28 [info] 8604#0: *106419381 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.151.2, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:28 [info] 8603#0: *106419382 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.121.100.131, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:28 [info] 8603#0: *106419383 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.121.100.129, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8603#0: *106419384 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.151.128, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8604#0: *106419385 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.152.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8604#0: *106419386 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.152.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8603#0: *106419387 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.152.129, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8604#0: *106419388 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.151.129, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8603#0: *106419389 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.151.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8603#0: *106419390 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.120.152.131, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/04/23 12:34:29 [info] 8604#0: *106419391 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.120.151.2, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:30 [info] 8603#0: *106419392 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while waiting for request, client: 100.121.100.131, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/23 12:34:30 [info] 8603#0: *106419393 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: 100.121.100.129, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

nginx configure

```
user  www www;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
error_log  logs/error.log  warn;
error_log  logs/error.log  error;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;

}
```

please help me, thanks for you!

Answer (score -1):

This problem has been solved.
This problem is caused by alicloud load balancer using TCP protocol for health check. Just change the health check protocol to http

Comment: is that applicable to other providers and loadbalancers?